# How to make a website locally hosted behind a proxy to be accessable outside?

Tags: domains, proxy

In our organization, we have a locally hosted website example.com which can't be access from outside of the organization.

Organization also have a proxy server, which we use to access the internet.

So, I am trying the example.com from home. I think it can be done if I run some server on my office PC have some domain like abc.com so when I access abc.com it fetches the example.com and sends it to the client on internet.

I have tried several things:

- manually writen a server that fetches and sends the website
- ngrok

But I am only able to access the webpage. It just takes the html files and sends it to the client. But I cant do things like submit form etc.

Comment: Did my answer end up working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try an ngrok TCP tunnel. This will expose your service directly without any modification of the HTTP data by ngrok.

Just run:

```
ngrok tcp 80
```

...if your web server is running HTTP on port 80.

This tunnels the port at the transport layer rather than at the application layer, so you will get a raw forwarding of the data without ngrok modifying it or adding HTTPS or breaking your forms and whatnot.

---

I am giving this answer on the strict assumption that what you are doing is **not against company policy**, and that you are only doing it because it is too much trouble to get the help of IT for a real exception in the proxy/firewall.